# Symfony2 login fails when session.storage.filesystem is set for storage_id

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to do some functional testing with PHPUnit but it requires that I add session.storage.filesystem for the storage_id option in config.yml.
This causes the login process to fail, for some reason. I get the following error in test.log :
Authentication request failed: Your session has timed-out, or you have disabled cookies.
Afterwards I'm redirected to the login page again. I'm certain that I have cookies enabled and that the application works without setting that option(with native session storage).
Could anyone tell me whether there is any solution for this issue?

Comment: Can your php write in session.storage path?

Comment: Please, paste contents of your `config.yml`

Comment: How could I find the session.storage path? I'm running symfony2 on Linux

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the app/cache/test/sessions folder. It is open for writing to everybody, so it shouldn't be a permission issue.

Comment: Is it Symfony 2.0 o 2.1?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I suddenly started running into this problem after incorporating FOSFacebookBundle into my Symfony 2.0 app. I need to use it along with FOSUserBundle. Also, what requires session.storage.filesystem and why?

Comment: @AdamMonsen Hi, Adam. Unfortunately I haven't had time to continue investigating this issue after posting the question. From what I recall, in my case the functional tests were not working unless I added this configuration option(PHPUnit behaviour) and then the login problem occured. The thing is that the application does not find the authentication cookie anymore and therefore the user cannot login. I suspect that the cookie is not actually persisted to the filesystem as would be expected from this setting but I have yet to find out why. Please let me know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try at changing your file permissions for the cache folder. If they're not set properly , this is what will happen:

- You develop stuff and test it through your web browser => your apache (or other server) will create the cache and will be the only one to have permissions on it
- You start phpunit tests from the command line (different unix user) => the current unix user does not have write access to your cache folder and cannot store the sessions.

Immediate fix to validate that this is the case:

```
chmod -R 777 app/cache/
phpunit -c app/
```

If this is actually the case, then go check how to properly set the rights at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup